# tex4ebook: Fatal error - Command tex4ht returned exit code 1

Tags: miktex, tex4ht, texniccenter, make4ht, tex4ebook

I try to use tex4ebook with MikTex and TeXnicCenter, but it always leads to a fatal error.

My simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

I tried a lot of different commands to be passed to the Compiler, e.g.

```
-c config.cfg -f epub3 "%wm"
```

but it does not work. The output/error is like that:

```
tex4ebook> [WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found
tex4ebook> [WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's
tex4ebook> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10)
tex4ebook> entering extended mode
tex4ebook> [FATAL] make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1
```

Which commands have to be passed to the Compiler in TeXnicCenter to make tex4ebook running?

Comment: try to add the `-a debug` option to see full error log, and post it here. TeX4ebook hides log by default and it can contain some information why it fails on your machine.

Comment: @michal.h21: Thanks for the hint - I had to copy the bibtex.exe and makeindex.exe from miktex/bin/x64 one folder up to miktex/bin - now it works :-)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't suspecting `bibtex` or `makeindex` to be culprits, but I am glad that you found the fix :)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I would not have found it without the full error log :)